# What causes infinite iteration in this Linked List node addition code?

Tags: c, linked-list

Having a bit of trouble with this Linked List code. I want to iterate through the list and add a new node to the tail end of the list, however, my while loop runs infinitely on a third addition.

```
struct node *w = calloc(...);
w->next = NULL;

struct node **r = &(list)->nodes;

if(r == NULL){
  *r = w;
}else{
  
  while(*r != NULL){
    
    if((*r)->next == NULL){
      (*r)->next = w;
       break;
    }
    (*r) = (*r)->next;

 }
}
```

The first two additions set the nodes (I check with print statements), however, on the third addition the code enters into an infinite loop. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is `(list)->nodes`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Doing `*r = w;` after making sure that `r == NULL` is nonsense.

Comment: `(*r) = (*r)->next;` doesn't do what you think, either. That sets the head to the last node.

Comment: Tip: if _all_ your code has `(*r)` then you may be using a variable `r` that has too much indirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
if(r == NULL){
  *r = w;
```

For a start, this is dead wrong.  If `r` is null, then `*r` is undefined behaviour.

It's a little hard to say what it *should* be since we can't see all your code but, at an initial guess, I'd suspect you should be comparing `*r` rather than `r`. But that's a guess, however educated it may be.